# Product $\sigma$-algebra: How can I prove that it's generated by cylinders since it's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra s.t. projections are measurable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

How can I prove that if $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$ and if $J\subset \mathbb R$ is s.t. $|J|=\infty$, then the product $\sigma$-algebra is $$\mathcal F^J=\sigma \left\{\prod_{j\in J}B_j\mid \forall j\in J, B_j\in \mathcal F, B_j\neq X\text{ for a finite number of }j\right\}.$$

To me, $\mathcal F^J$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra s.t. projection are continuous ie $$\mathcal F^J:=\sigma \{\pi_j^{-1}(F)\mid F\in \mathcal F, j\in J\}=\sigma \{X\times ...\times F\times ...\times X\times ...\mid F\in \mathcal F\}$$
where $F$ is at the $j$-th place and $\pi_j$ is the projection on the $j$-th variable. So only one $B_i$ in $\prod_{j\in J}B_j$ is different of $X$. So for me $\prod_{j\in J}B_j$ with $B_j\neq X$ for a countable number of $j$ is in $\mathcal F^J$ (not only finite number of $j$). Could someone give me some explanations ?

---

I know that $X\times ...\times X\times ...$ is not really adapted for $\prod_{j\in J}X$ when $J$ is not countable, but I think it's more visual here... So I abused a little bit of the notation to be more clear :)

Comment: your question really confuses me

Comment: How can the product measure be a $\sigma$-algebra? These two things (measures and $\sigma$-algebras) are totally different objects

Comment: @saz: I corrected it. I wante to say : product $\sigma -$algebra.

Comment: @saz: For me it's correct. Indeed, $\prod_{j\in J}B_j$ s.t. $B_j\neq X$ for a countable number of $j$ is in $$\sigma \left\{\prod_{j\in J}\mid \forall j, B_j\in \mathcal F, B_t\neq X\text{ for a finite number of $j$}\right\}.$$ Why for you it's not correct ?

Comment: @Surb Argh, I missed the "$\sigma$" in front of the brackets; sorry...  you are absolutely right

Comment: ok, so why $\mathcal F^J=\sigma \{\prod_{j\in J}B_j\mid \forall j, B_j\in \mathcal F, B_j\neq X\text{ for a finite number of }j\}$ and not $\mathcal F^J=\sigma \{\prod_{j\in J}B_j\mid \forall j, B_j\in \mathcal F, B_j\neq X\text{ for exactly one }j\}$ ? @saz and Surb

Comment: @user601023 Both of them are correct. Note that $\sigma$-algebras are stable under (countable) intersections ...